Matlab Bode Plot of 4th-Order High Pass Butterworth Filter
I am designing a digital 4th order Butterworth filter in Matlab, and am attempting to gather a bode plot of the system.
The bode plot the Matlab seems to set the frequency and magnitude extremely low, and when attempting to force the bode plot into the correct ranges using bodeoptions I just get an extremely warped output.


I have arrived at the transfer function mathematically with the values as found in den and num at the top of the code, and have checked this is correct, along with the poles and zeroes, by cross checking with the Matlab Filter Designer app, which gives a correct magnitude and phase response on the bode plot.

I have tried several plotoption varieties, as well as playing with the sampling frequency, trying to use the sampling time and none give me the desired response.
den = [1,2.257,2.54696,1.68372,0.556516];
num = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
fs = 44100
Ts = 1 / fs 
Hz = tf(num, den, Ts);
plotoptions = bodeoptions;
plotoptions.FreqUnits = 'kHz';
plotoptions.FreqScale = 'linear';
plotoptions.MagLowerLimMode = 'manual';
plotoptions.YLim = {[-80, 50];[-360, 360.002]};
plotoptions.XLim = {[0, 25]};
plotoptions.Grid = 'on';
bodeplot(Hz, plotoptions)

